# Potion of Protection from Arrows 15/magic?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, potions

According to the SRD:
https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm

It lists a Potion of Protection from Arrows with 15/magic is this a mistake? According to the spell this should not be possible as the damage reduction is only 10/magic.

https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromArrows.htm

If this is not a mistake, should the part which reads:

*'Once the spell has prevented a total of 10 points of damage per caster level (maximum 100 points), it is discharged.'*

instead be adjusted by understood implication to read

'*Once the spell has prevented a total of 15 points of damage per caster level (maximum 150 points), it is discharged.*'

when applied to this particular potion? I have read the 3.5 DMG errata and nothing is mentioned in regards to this.

Comment: Looks like it is just a higher level of potion. Up to 100 points, the first one is 10 points, the second is 15. You could have one of X where X <= 100. That would be my interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It may be more powerful...

The regular *[protection from arrows](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#protection-from-arrows)* potion costs 300, the more [powerful one](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsPRR.html#potions) costs 1500 gp, and is 50% more effective. By the [creation rules](http://creating-potions), to get that price, the caster level would have to be 10th, and the spell level 3rd, or perhaps caster level 15, but that doesn't give anything other than duration. In Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 revision rules...

### ... because it fell through the cracks

It appears it's a holdover from the 3.5 update, likely from a version of *protection from arrows* that became more protective with caster level, as the 3rd edition version required higher magical bonuses depending on caster level, eventually getting to requiring +5 arrows to bypass the DR (*Player's Handbook* 2000, 240, emphasis mine).

> The damage reduction increases with caster level to 10/+2 at 5th, ***10/+3 at 10th***[...]

I suspect that the authors and editors had an interim playtest version of the spell where instead of the magic bonus increasing, the DR itself did, since they had changed the way that DR worked, but eventually settled on the version in the 2003 *Player's Handbook, 3.5 edition revision*.

It's a mistake, but not a *typo*.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a mistake

The only thing a potion can do is duplicate the effect of an existing spell. The [Brew Potion](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#brewPotion) Item Creation Feat lets you „create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures.“ The potion then holds the spell. There is no way to brew a potion that is more efficient than the spell which was used to create it.

The Spell *Protection from Arrows* grants damage reduction 10/magic against ranged weapons. It cannot provide more, the benefit does not scale with the caster level. As a consequence, a potion *Protection from Arrows 15/magic* cannot exist.

Comment: It's not a potion I was considering creating. It's more of the fact it exist as a randomly generated magic item. You say it's a mistake yet it has never been picked up in an errata document.

Comment: @MichaelDorf  Nevertheless it shouldn't be on that list. It simply doesn't follow the rules for creating potions - which are very clear.